# Obscure usages of C++ virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

The virtual inheritance in C++ is an useful way to prevent the diamond issue. However, I can't seem to make it work properly in each and every case.

This is going to be very hard to explain but I hope I'll manage. Let's present the problem:

A inherits B. And A is the base class of a class set called C and another class set called D.

The problem is that the C set of class have common features focusing around B.

What I would like to do, but isn't possible, is a class E that virtually inherits B, and which is inherited by C. Problem is:

In this case, A doesn't virtually inherits B. So it doesn't work.

If A was to virtually inherit B, then I would need to use B's constructor in every classes of D.

Conclusion: in *every* case there is duplicated code. How may I get out of this issue without any duplicated code ?

Comment: give a short example of what does not work.

Comment: Given what you've told us so far, those two options are your only options - have two copies of B in E, or put up with explicitly constructing B everywhere. There's probably a better design, but without background on what the classes are and why the inheritance tree is like that, no one's going to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so you are saying that you have:

```
                             B
                             +
                             |
                             v
                             A
                             +
                        +----+----+
                        v         v
                        C         D
```

And all of these are non-virtual inheritance and then you have class `E` that *virtualy* inherits `B` and `C` also inherits it so a complete diagram would be:

```
                +-----------+B
                |            +
                |            |
                v            v
                E            A
                +            +
                +---+---+----+----+
                    v             v
                    C             D
```

With the exception that `B` is *virtualy* inherited by `E`.

The solution is simple you should make `A` also virtually inherit `B`, however I gathered from your question that you can not modify `A`. Your next option is to make `C` inherit `A` or `E` and have an instance of the other this is called [delegation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29)
An alternative you can provide a common interface and allow polymorphism you might want to make an interface (pure virtual class) that has all the function in `E` that `C` uses and then make `C` and `E` derive that interface. `E` would implement the virtual functions from the interface and C would implement it as function calls to `E`'s implementation. Alternatively (not recommended) you can live with the diamond of death if it is not problematic for you, however determining that is tricky and I don't recommend this it's a terrible idea.

Comment: You should reverse the inheritance arrows so it follows the uml convention. The arrow should point to the class being inherited from rather than the class doing the inheriting.

Comment: Thank you ! The third option did the trick: it allows me to keep the API as it currently is while making the code dry.
There's a little caveat here: virtual methods from the interface that are implemented in A rather than B cannot be solved for classes inheriting E (it's ambiguous). I'll work around that anyway, this is still the best possible option by far.

Answer (score 1):

Split `B` into an interface part `IB` (an abstract base class, no data members) and an implementation part `Bimpl`. Multiply-inherit *only* `IB`. Since `IB` has no data members, there's no need for a non-default constructor, so you don't have to repeat it everywhere.

For each class `C` in the hierarchy that becomes abstract because of this change, create `Cimpl` that inherits from both `C` and `Bimpl`. Never inherit from `Cimpl`. Non-default constructor(s) of `Bimpl`, formerly of `B`, are only called in `C`.